# Couchdb searching via multiple queries

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I have the following map function to index each specific alphanumeric word inside my document so I can search for it.

```
Array.prototype.map = function(func) {
    var i, r = [];
    for(i = 0; i < this.length; i += 1) {
        r[i] = func(this[i]);
    }
    return r;
};

Array.prototype.reduce = function(val, func) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < this.length; i += 1) {
        val = func(val, this[i]);
    }
    return val;
}

Array.prototype.uniq = function() {
    return this.reduce([], function(list, e) {
        if (list.indexOf(e) < 0) {
            return list.concat([e]);
        } else {
            return list;
        }
    });
}

function(doc) {
    var tokens;
    if (doc.name) {
        tokens = doc.name.toLowerCase().split(/[^A-Z0-9\-_]+/i).uniq();
        tokens.map(function(token) {
            emit(token, doc);
        });
    }
}
```

So if I do something like:

```
db.view('documents/keywords', { key: "hello" });
```

It will list every document with the word `hello` in it.

My question is, if I want to find something that has both the word `hello` and the word `world`, is there a more efficient way of doing this then doing two queries to my view, and then client side figure out which id's pop up in both queries?

My worry is it will start being troublesome at scale when I have 1,000 `hello`s and completely different amount of `world`s

Comment: It sounds like you're implementing full text search, so is there any reason you aren't including a proper engine like [lucene](https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene) or [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-couchdb_changes.html)?

Comment: @DominicBarnes various reasons. I needed something quick and don't really know how to go about doing it, I don't want to manage another server, don't have any money to spend on another service, etc. I might be completely off basis for this but was just more interested in the indexing concept to learn more about views